# I have to create a search box that searches alphanumeric string, normal string and numbers from table in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sorting, angular-pipe

I already used a Angular pipe that filters string. But unable to filters alphanumeric character string(XYZ-001/2023, XYZ-063/2023) or number. So I need a logic or pipe in angular that filters string, number and alphanumeric string.

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: Regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a pipe that uses a regular expression to match against the input string:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'alphanumericFilter'
})
export class AlphanumericFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], searchText: string, propertyName: string): any[] {
    if (!items) return [];
    if (!searchText) return items;

    const regex = new RegExp(searchText, 'i');

    return items.filter(item => {
      // convert the value of the specified property to a string
      const propertyValueString = item[propertyName].toString();

      // check if the property value matches the regular expression
      return regex.test(propertyValueString);
    });
  }

}
```

JSON.stringify is used to convert each item to a string before matching.
Then, in your component's template, you can use the pipe to filter your table:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchText">
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of items | alphanumericFilter: searchText">
    <td>{{ item }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And don't forget to add it to your module's declarations:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AlphanumericFilterPipe } from './alphanumeric-filter.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [AlphanumericFilterPipe],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: 2 things here I have to ask,
1- I have to write alphanumerical regular expression at  const regex = new RegExp(searchText, 'i'). Or is this code enough.
2- I think, at very first line tranform(item:any[],searchText: string), here item:any[] will search the items, that is present in array directly. But I have to search the item that present in array of object.

Comment: 1-Indeed you need to edit the searchText with a regular expression like: `const searchText = /^[\w-\s]+(?:\/\d{4})?$/;`
2-Yes, in that case you will need to modify the implementation of the transform method.

I have edited my answer with those changes.